# Xcode IBOutlets not showing in storybuilder

Tags: xcode, storyboard, iboutlet

This is my code in the 
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *text1;
}

@end
```

It simply does not show up when i want it to be an outlet to the textbox i have in my storyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What class is your view controller set to in your storyboard?

Comment: No idea how to figure that out?

Comment: Heh never mind figured it out. Thanks.